# None-type object returned for selected radiobutton

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x

I have a case where I want to use radio buttons as my query option so I can get correct query set according to selected radio button.
I can not find a way to get selected radio button value in form. There are a lot of info about using form class. what about simple html form. part of form is:

```
<label for="house-all-id">All</label>
<input type="radio" id="house-all-id" name="h-type" value="0"/>
<label for="house-orp-id">Just case one</label>
<input type="radio" id="house-orp-id" name="h-type" value="1"/>
<label for="house-inm-id">Just case two</label>
<input type="radio" id="house-inm-id" name="h-type" value="2"/>
```

These radio-buttons are part of a from with another widgets to help my get correct QuerySet. In view:

```
    h_type = request.POST.get('h_type')
```

This returns a none-type object. How can I get value of selected radio button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your fields are named "h-type" but you're trying to access "h_type".